# Compare two different images and find the differences

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have a webcam which takes pictures of a concrete slab. Now I want to check if there are objects on the slab or not. The objects could be anything and accordingly cannot be enumerated in a class. Unfortunately I cannot compare the webcam image directly with an image without objects on the concrete slab, because the image of the camera could shift minimally in x and y direction and the lighting is also not always the same. So I cannot use `cv2.substract`.
I would prefer a foreground and background substract, where the background is just my concrete slab and the foreground is then the objects. But since the objects don´t move but lie still on the slab, I can´t use `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` either.

The Pictures look like this:

The Concrete slap without any objects:

[image]

The slap with Objects:

[image]   [image]

Comment: You could check for differences in the histograms of the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python/OpenCV, you could do division normalization to even out the illumination and make the background white. Then do your subtraction. Then use morphology to clean up small regions. Then find contours and discard any small regions that are due to noise left after the division normalization and morphology.

Here is how to do division normalization.

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (0,0), sigmaX=13, sigmaY=13)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (0,0), sigmaX=13, sigmaY=13)

# divide
divide1 = cv2.divide(gray1, blur1, scale=255)
divide2 = cv2.divide(gray2, blur2, scale=255)

# threshold
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(divide1, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(divide2, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
morph1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
morph1 = cv2.morphologyEx(morph1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(morph2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("img1_division_normalize.jpg", divide1)
cv2.imwrite("img2_division_normalize.jpg", divide2)
cv2.imwrite("img1_division_morph1.jpg", morph1)
cv2.imwrite("img1_division_morph2.jpg", morph2)


# display it
cv2.imshow("img1_norm", divide1)
cv2.imshow("img2_norm", divide2)
cv2.imshow("img1_thresh", thresh1)
cv2.imshow("img2_thresh", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("img1_morph", morph1)
cv2.imshow("img2_morph", morph2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image 1 Normalized:

[image]

Image 2 Normalized:

[image]

Image 1 thresholded and morphology cleaned:

[image]

Image 2 thresholded and morphology cleaned:

[image]

In this case, Image 1 becomes completely white. So it (and subtraction) is not really needed. You just need to find contours for the second image result and if necessary discard tiny regions by area. The rest are your objects.